# Why actionscript load does not work with bmp file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Curious why [Loder.load](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load%28%29) works with

> JPEG, progressive JPEG, unanimated GIF, or PNG file

but excludes BMP image type.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player doesn't supports BMP format, but you can load/use it with this class:
http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/BMPDecoder/src/com/voidelement/images/BMPDecoder.as

Answer (score 0):

Flash don't support it. Because it's to expensive. You want BMP, some other want NEF. Others want some other... it's impossible.

You can find ready-to use third-party SWC or open source solution that can load BMP to Flash also the rest formats.